# Destroy specific session data on complete order

Tags: magento-1.9, session

I am using Magento 1.9.

When I want to destroy a specific session in Magento I run this code:

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->unsPcPayment();
```

But I want to execute this code when an order is completed.

How can I do this? Where should I put this code?

NOTE: I do not want to destroy this session when the order is paid, I just want to destroy the session when the order is simply received.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to create an observer in a module, preferrable your own module in the local code pool:

```
<!-- app/code/local/Mymodule/etc/config.xml -->
...
<global>
    <events>
        ...
        <sales_order_place_after>
            <observers>
                <clear_session>
                    <class>Mymodule_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>clearCheckoutSession</method>
                </clear_session>
            </observers>
        </sales_order_place_after>
    </events>
</global>
...
```

Don't know how this works? See here:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method

Once you declare the observer, build it out:

```
<?php

// app/code/local/Mymodule/Model/Observer.php

class Mymodule_Model_Observer 
    extends Varien_Event_Observer
{

    public function clearCheckoutSession()
    {
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->clear(); // Or whatever you want to clear
    }

}
```

You'll want to customize this to your needs, obviously. And put some verification checks in there as well.

**EDIT:** As per laketuna's suggestion, I changed the target event to `sales_order_place_after`, as it seems to be the most reliable one to observe.

Comment: I have my own module like `/app/code/core/local/Vivas/PercentPayment` so how it will look like in your answer ? Also, does `<method>clearCheckoutSession</method>` means that the xml is "telling" to run the `public function clearCheckoutSession()` ? Thanks for your answer dude!

Comment: yep, you got it. Read the article referenced for the full details on that part. In your module, translate all the references from `Mymodule` to `PercentPayment`, and place the config XML in `app/code/core/local/Vivas/PercentPayment/etc/config.xml` as part of the `global` node.

Comment: I strongly suggest hooking onto the `sales_order_place_after` event instead of `sales_model_service_quote_submit_after` to ensure the order is completed successfully.

Comment: Good call, @laketuna. I'm updating my answer to reflect that.

Comment: It seems it's not working for me. I've placed `Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->unsPcPayment();` instead of `Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->clear();` but it's not destroying this session.

Comment: Can you verify that the event triggers? ie: use a `die` or other debugging statement in there? If no, then your config XML might be wrong. If yes, then are you clearing the correct session? `core/session`, `customer/session`, `checkout/session`?

Answer (score 0):

you can try to put an observer in checkout_onepage_controller_success_action (or some event after the order is placed).

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <GP_Savesku>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </GP_Savesku>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <gp_savesku>
                <class>GP_Savesku_Model</class>
            </gp_savesku>
        </models>
        <events>
            <checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
                <observers>
                    <gp_savesku>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>gp_savesku/observer</class>
                        <method>saveSku</method>
                    </gp_savesku>
                </observers>
            </checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

Observer.php

```
class GP_Savesku_Model_Observer {
 public function saveSku($observer){
    if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getDummy()){
      Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->unsDummy();
    }
 }
}
```

Is working on a production enviroment right now :)

Comment: You should probably not just copy and paste your code - if you're going to go to the trouble of creating the module you should change it's name to at least hide your copy and pasting :) Besides that, you're missed the `app/etc/modules` entry, and it'd be handy to specify the file paths for each file incase the OP doesn't know where the Observer model should go